# What are some ways I can draw attention to a UIBarButtonItem when the text changes?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I'm building an iPhone game and I have a UIBarButtonItem that will provide the user with a hint to solve the puzzle when pressed.  When the user earns a hint, the text on the UIBarButtonItem is updated to show the current number of hints available.  The problem is, the hint count starts at zero and when I update the text and play a little notification sound, it's still not easily recognizable to the user that they've earned a hint as they're learning to play the game.  As such, I'd like to draw some attention to the UIBarButtonItem when I play the notification sound and update the text.

How can I draw attention to a UIBarButtonItem in the nav bar?  Is there a way to make it flash?  Can I use Core Animation to animate the UIBarButtonItem?  Do I have to create a custom UIButton view to accomplish this?  I'd prefer not to since that route involves making more art.

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always set the style of the BarButton to "Done" style when an action happens. If your Navbar or Toolbar *(whichever houses the button)* is set to normal, then the button should turn Blue.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea.  What I can do is set a timer to swap the styles a few times a second and that should make it flash.  Thanks for the idea, I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Sounds like it could work, or you could use a UIView animation sequence/.